# go back before .text() is used

Tags: jquery

On hover content is being replaced, but when the mouse leaves the element I want it to change back. How would I do this?

```
$('.img-wrap').hover(function(){
      $(this).find('h4').text('Go to site');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the original text in `$.data` in the first callback, then read it in the second callback.

For example:

```
$('.img-wrap').hover(function(){
    var h4 = $(this).find('h4');
    h4.data('oldText', h4.text()).text('Go to site');
}, function() { 
     $(this).find('h4').text(function() { return $.data(this, "oldText"); });    
});
```

Comment: The original text would be changed by the client, so is there anything I can do? Maybe copy whatever in the element then reusing it?

Comment: @Trippy: What do you mean?  That's exactly what this code does.

Comment: h4.data('oldText' I would need to insert the old text right? But the old text will be changed by people at some point. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Trippy: `'oldText'` is the name of the `data` field.  `h4.text()` is the value.  Read the documentation.  http://api.jquery.com/data . . http://api.jquery.com/text

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) it is shortcut for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Luq8/)

Comment: That also really isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the text before you replace it:

```
$('.img-wrap').mouseenter(function(){
    var $h4 = $(this).find('h4');
    $(this).data("old-text", $h4.text());
    $h4.text('Go to site');
}). mouseleave(function() {
    var $h4 = $(this).find('h4');
    $h4.text($(this).data("old-text"));
    $(this).data("old-text", null);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: `hover` fires when you get in any element contained into `.img-wrap`, and in the div itselfs. Using `mouseenter` prevents you of getting duplicated events when you move the mouse over the element. Good luck! http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: @Gonzalo: You are wrong. `hover` calls `mouseenter`.  You're describing `mouseover`, which `hover` has nothing to do with.

Comment: You're right. I've misreaded it.But as `hover` is a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, what's wrong with using them anyway?.

Comment: Looks good except I can't just insert the old text in JS, the old text will be changed a  lot.

Comment: @Trippy. Why? Are you using HTML inside the <h4 />? Could you give us an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the API for the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)-function.
You can do it by passing an extra function:

```
$('.img-wrap').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('h4').text('Go to site');
},
function() {
   $(this).find('h4').text(''); 
});
```